# How to create an XP system discord bot (java)

Tags: java, timer, gson, discord

I've been creating this bot (named Rikka) for a few months now. I've created over 60 commands. I recently wanted to add an XP system for her, but I'm having quite a lot of issues. Namely with the message cooldown (Only adds xp to a user every minute on message) and saving the user's ID and xp level to a JSON file. If anyone could help (preferably spoon-feed me the code, but walking me through it is also okay) it would be massively appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: XP? What does that mean?

Comment: @JamesKPolk XP = Experience. Basically what it would do is add a random int from 0 - 25 to a playerXp value, rewrite the .json file (that holds all user information), edit that user's specific key and add the random int to the current int that's in there.

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't "spoon-feed" the code to you.